# How do I make my algo work with KNN text classification?

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, knn, text-classification

Trying to make my classification accepting a text (string) and not just a number (numeric). Working with data, carrying a load of pulled articles, I want the classification algo to show which ones to proceed with and which ones to drop. Applying a number, things are working just fine, yet this is not very intuitive, although I know that the number represents a relationship to one of the two classes I am working with.

How do I change the logic in the algo to make it accept a text as search criteria and not just an anonymous number, picked from the 'Unique_id' column? Columns are, btw...'Title', 'Abstract', 'Relevant', 'Label', 'Unique_id'. The reason for concatenating df's at algo end is that I want to compare results. Finally. it should be noted that the col 'Label' consists of a list of keywords, so basically I want the algo to read from that col.

I did try, reading from data sources, changing the '*index_col='Unique_id*' to '*index_col='Label*', but that did not work out either.

An example of what I want:

```
print("\nPrint KNN1")
print(get_closest_neighs1('search word'), "\n")

print("\nPrint KNN2")
print(get_closest_neighs2('search word'), "\n")

print("\nPrint KNN3")
print(get_closest_neighs3('search word'), "\n")
```

This is the full code (view end of algo to see above example as it runs today, using a number to identify nearest neighbor):

```
import pandas as pd

print("\nPerforming Analysis using Text Classification")
data = pd.read_csv('File_1_coltest_demo.csv', sep=';',  encoding="ISO-8859-1").dropna()

data['Unique_id'] = data.groupby(['Title', 'Abstract', 'Relevant']).ngroup()

data.to_csv('File_2_coltest_demo_KNN.csv', sep=';', encoding="ISO-8859-1", index=False)

data1 = pd.read_csv('File_2_coltest_demo_KNN.csv', sep=';', encoding="ISO-8859-1", index_col='Unique_id')

data2 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=['Abstract', 'Relevant'])

data2.to_csv('File_3_coltest_demo_KNN_reduced.csv', sep=';', encoding="ISO-8859-1", index=False)

print("\nData top 25 items")
print(data2.head(25))

print("\nData info")
print(data2.info())

print("\nData columns")
print(data2.columns)

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer

token = RegexpTokenizer(r'[a-zA-Z0-9]+')
cv = CountVectorizer(lowercase=True, stop_words='english', ngram_range=(1, 1), tokenizer=token.tokenize)
text_counts = cv.fit_transform(data2['Abstract'])

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
text_counts, data2['Abstract'], test_size=0.5, random_state=1)

print("\nTF IDF")
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
tf = TfidfVectorizer()
text_tf = tf.fit_transform(data2['Abstract'])
print(text_tf)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
text_tf, data2['Abstract'], test_size=0.3, random_state=123)

from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
import pandas as pd

nbrs = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=20, metric='euclidean').fit(text_tf)

def get_closest_neighs1(Abstract):
    row = data2.index.get_loc(Abstract)
    distances, indices = nbrs.kneighbors(text_tf.getrow(row))
    names_similar = pd.Series(indices.flatten()).map(data2.reset_index()['Abstract'])
    result = pd.DataFrame({'distance1' : distances.flatten(), 'Abstract' : names_similar}) # 'Unique_id' : names_similar,
    return result

def get_closest_neighs2(Unique_id):
    row = data2.index.get_loc(Unique_id)
    distances, indices = nbrs.kneighbors(text_tf.getrow(row))
    names_similar = pd.Series(indices.flatten()).map(data2.reset_index()['Unique_id'])
    result1 = pd.DataFrame({'Distance' : distances.flatten() / 10, 'Unique_id' : names_similar}) # 'Unique_id' : names_similar,
    return result1

def get_closest_neighs3(Relevant):
    row = data2.index.get_loc(Relevant)
    distances, indices = nbrs.kneighbors(text_tf.getrow(row))
    names_similar = pd.Series(indices.flatten()).map(data2.reset_index()['Relevant'])
    result2 = pd.DataFrame({'distance2' : distances.flatten(), 'Relevant' : names_similar}) # 'Unique_id' : names_similar,
    return result2

print("\nPrint KNN1")
print(get_closest_neighs1(114), "\n")

print("\nPrint KNN2")
print(get_closest_neighs2(114), "\n")

print("\nPrint KNN3")
print(get_closest_neighs3(114), "\n")

data3 = pd.DataFrame(get_closest_neighs1(114))
data4 = pd.DataFrame(get_closest_neighs2(114))
data5 = pd.DataFrame(get_closest_neighs3(114))

del data5['distance2']

data6 = pd.concat([data3, data4, data5], axis=1).reindex(data3.index)

del data6['distance1']

data6.to_csv('File_4_coltest_demo_KNN_results.csv', sep=';', encoding="ISO-8859-1", index=False)
```

Comment: Could you provide a short extract of the first CSV?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right you are trying to do this:

- You have vectorised all your documents by their "Abstract" field. Therefore documents with abstracts with similar word distributions should be nearby in TFIDF space.
- You want to find the nearest neighbours to a document which has the search keyword.
- Therefore you'd need to search the original corpus for the first or all documents which have that keyword
- then find the index of that/those document(s), and then find their neighbours.
- if there are multiple documents with that keyword, you would need to sort the index list and merge the overall results somehow with some weightings.

If this is true, then the keyword search/lookup isn't really "inside" the model, it's just preselecting a document from the corpus. Once you have the document index, you can perform the KNN (repeatedly).

I'm not hugely familiar with Pandas, but I've done this kind of thing "manually" before e.g. by keeping the document titles in a separate array, with a map to the indexes.

I would imagine you would need to replace your data2.index.get_loc() calls with an iteration over the column values for "Label" and do a simple string search on each. Or does Pandas provide search functions within the corpus?

e.g. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html#pandas.DataFrame.query

Comment: Hi scipilot, thx for responding to my issue, you're pretty much right in your way of looking at my issue...;o) Are you suggesting that the entire text analysis part is not necessary, and that I should search directly in the original corpus? I guess that the very reason for performing pre-processing like TF-IDF and stuff is to take advantage of the intuition that if a word occurs multiple times in a document, relevance that doc or any other I select for scrutiny in my corpus, is being boosted. I may be getting you wrong, tried to change a bit of the code, i.e. get_loc to .query

Comment: Could you possibly come up with an example of how I should apply what you're suggesting? - thx

Comment: Actually, I do try to make an index out of col 'Label', then pointing to the corresponding item in col 'Abstract'. I am sure I am doing a stupid mistake, but I cannot dig out where that error hides...;o/...;o)

Comment: It depends what you are trying to achieve. If you want to find unlabelled documents near to labelled ones (i.e. you don't trust the original labelling) then its good to utilise the TFIDF neighbours. But if you believe the labels were right to start with, then you could just search the original corpus by the label column and not even bother vectorising them.

Comment: I would argue that a list of 2k+ text strings (i.e. different scientific abstracts) is unlabeled data, which is also why I perform the TF-IDF

Comment: I was referring to the 'Label' column in your original import - I presumed that was the keywords from the original documents? (e.g. the RIS KW rows?)

Comment: OK, you're absolutely right, I will work with that..;o) - thx